# Multiboot system fails to boot "last used OS"

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown

I am looking **for explanation** why

stopping the system using terminal "shutdown" command
reboots - on next " power-up " - **using different firmware "Ubuntu"**
HENCE FAILURE

while
turning off the system power
reboots - on next "power-up" into SAME , last used firmware "Ubuntu"
and its option to boot into last OS used
HENCE SUCCESS

I realize my system setup is little convoluted,
but I believe that should not cause this issue.

My gut feeling "shutdown" MAY have an issue and my next step should be to analyze
"shut down" messages. BUT how ? After the fact...
Is there a log / journal BEFORE next boot wipes it off ?

( PS I run other devices from common power strip and  would prefer PC to "shutdown" before turning off the power strip power - just my preference )

Comment: Grub sets a flag on boot, and clears is as one of last steps of normal shutdown. If flag set on boot, it boots to recovery mode, so you can make repairs. I have not unmounted something, and then shutdown takes a long time as it has to time out, often a minute & half per device. I like to do this. Change grub from quiet splash to noplymouth, will see boot process rather than Ubuntu logo, also then shows shutdown. Same info that is in logs.

Comment: I have all grubs optioned to show progress messages , both on boot and after "shutdown", so that is not the issue, BUT the issue MAY be the flag remains set after "shutdown". I have to check if it runs "recovery mode" , but I think it does, but it does not brings up  the recovery  dialog... but it tells it is in "emergency mode "...